# Add weight parameter in a custom module

Tags: 7

I created a content type and it has many nodes. And I wrote a custom module to show nodes on the front page.

My nodes order:

```
 $themeurl = '/drupal/'.path_to_theme().'/images';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `node`
            LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk` ON `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
            WHERE type = 'designers_albums'
            AND `node`.`status` = 1
            AND `node`.`language` = '".$language->language."'
            AND `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`field_anasayfa_catwalk_value` = 1
            ORDER BY `node`.`created` ASC";
```

But now, I installed the [Weight](http://drupal.org/project/weight) module and want to sort by weight. How can I change this option?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just have to add another JOIN to the weight_weights table on your query.

The weight_weights table stores the entity_id, entity_type and the weight value.

EDITED

Here goes an example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `node`
        LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk` ON `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
        LEFT JOIN `weight_weights` ON `weight_weights`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
        WHERE type = 'designers_albums'
        AND `node`.`status` = 1
        AND `node`.`language` = '".$language->language."'
        AND `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`field_anasayfa_catwalk_value` = 1
        ORDER BY `weight_weights`.`weight` ASC";
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me sample?